# Позиционирование блоков, адаптивный дизайн

Tags: html, css

На странице много блоков заданной ширины и высоты, при изменении ширины экрана они адаптируются под нее. Но есть один блок шириной в два стандартных. Он всегда должен быть расположен в правом верхнем углу. Проблемы с отступом слева (прижат к правому краю), помогите прижать его влево.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div style="float:right; width: 200px; height: 100px; border: solid red 1px; ">проблемный блок</div>
 
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: left; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблемный блок прижимается к правому краю экрана, в то время как все остальные выстраиваются ровными рядами/колонками

Comment: Ну так он же там и должен быть, судя по описанию

Comment: Сложно было выразить мысль, наверно плохо получилось. Проблемный блок должен заменить два стандартных в правом верхнем углу. При изменении ширины экрана лишние в ряду должны перемещаться ниже

Comment: Что мешает скинуть рабочий пример, что бы его можно было "погонять" и понять что к чему? До сих пор ничего не понятно, откуда там 2 стандартных справа взялись? ...

Comment: Прошу прощения, не полный пример привел. Сейчас исправил. Проблема в левом отступе у проблемного блока.

Comment: То есть он должен прилегать к обычным блокам, но при этом они должны его "обтекать"?О_о На вскидку даже и не знаю можно ли такое чистым css'ом реализовать ....

Comment: Ну да, посмотрите на скрин (слева динамично изменяющийся отступ в зависимости от ширины экрана), думаете невозможно? )

Comment: пока думаю ... не представляю для чего это может пригодиться и пока что ничего из "нативного" придумать не могу, да даже как это на js описать не представляю ))))

Comment: не, без js тут точно не обойдется ....

Comment: Понятно, для меня это не менее важный комментарий, чем решение вопроса, иначе голову бы сломал на ложном пути, я сам-то слабоват. Но, если у кого-нибудь идеи будут для размышления, скиньте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div style="float:right; width: 200px; height: 98px; border: solid red 1px; ">проблемный блок</div>
 
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
<div style="float: right; width:100px;height: 100px;">стандартные блоки</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Задай всем div `float: right`. Думаю это будет самое простое решение проблемы

Comment: Не так не получится, проблемный блок должен всегда находится в правом верхнем углу. Решил при помощи js с показом блока в нужном месте, в зависимости от ширины окна